# Не получается установить Sleeping Owl

Tags: php, laravel

Не получается установить Sleeping Owl на Laravel 5.2.43.
Выдает ошибку

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()
```

Хотя сделал все по [инструкции](http://sleeping-owl.github.io/ru/Getting_Started/Installation.html). Как решить?

Comment: По какой инструкции? Укажите ссылку на плагин и инструкцию к нему, которую вы используете, а также версию Laravel.

Comment: http://sleeping-owl.github.io/ru/Getting_Started/Installation.html

Comment: 5.2.43 версия laravel

Answer (score 1):

Метод `bindShared()` объявили устаревшим. Используйте `singleton()`.
Если он используется в SleepingOwl, то проверьте, может есть новая версия или подождите её.

см. [документацию по апгрейду до 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade), [обсуждение на github](https://github.com/sleeping-owl/admin/issues/308), [форк](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin)

**upd:** пакет же официально заброшен. Используйте [LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin)

Comment: Не подскажете как обновить метод в sleeping owl?

Comment: Вообще, можно найти и заменить, но это плохо, потому что слетит при обновлении (хотя автор уже 8 месяцев не обновлял пакет) или надо будет держать в репе (а с vendor этого делать не стоит).

Comment: А какие альтернативные пакеты админки посоветуете для laravel?

Comment: Я обновил ответ. Автор на главной советует https://github.com/LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin

Comment: Благодарю, установил пакет от LaravelRus, файлы были созданы, но теперь выдает Class 'App\\Providers\AdminSectionsServiceProvider' not found при переходе на страницы

Comment: Команду ``php artisan sleepingowl:install`` выполнили?

Comment: Да, создались файлы

Comment: Ошибка именно с SleepingOwl\Admin\Providers\SleepingOwlServiceProvider::class, если убрать все открывается, по установке указано вставить этот код, после вставки такая вот беда

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44169/discussion-between-xedelweiss-and-asd).